# UserDefaults checking for nil value not working

Tags: swift, if-statement, nsuserdefaults, swift4

Any idea why my if statement always gives else answer?
I noticed from the print that the object is stored as "optional()", maybe this optional state is different from nil?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneDisplayLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func storeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Nb")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("\(phoneLabel.text!)", forKey: "Nb")
        print(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Nb") as Any)
    }

    @IBAction func retrieveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let phoneNB = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Nb")
        if let phoneNbDisplay = phoneNB as? String {
            if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Nb") != nil {
                phoneDisplayLabel.text = "Your NB is \(phoneNbDisplay)"
            }
            else {
                phoneDisplayLabel.text = "enter a number first"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() for safe operation. Some times object/value does not get save if we don't use synchronize

Comment: @Gagan_iOS, this is not needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "etc") != nil)
{
    if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "etc") as! String).character.count == 0
    {
        //value is ""
    }else{
        //having some value
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: **Do not** suggest `valueForKey` with `UserDefaults` unless you can explain why KVC is explicitly needed in this case, can you? There is a `string(forKey` method.

Comment: & also don't force unwrap

Comment: yes i know about that but u can also save in that another type values in my case i save array so

Comment: @Jack Force unwrap is fine, because the object is clearly not `nil`.

Comment: @DivyeshGondaliya There is `array(forKey` method  for arrays.

Comment: @vadian also for the UserDefaults

Comment: @DivyeshGondaliya Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

Comment: ok but its working fine in my condition and i already read this document @vadian and thanks for the document

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152240/discussion-between-divyesh-gondaliya-and-vadian).

Comment: Working code is not necessarily (most) efficient code.

Comment: show my latest update answer why i am not using this please explain me to improve my knowledge thanks in advanced @vadian

Comment: Have you ever read the [official reference of `UserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults). Check if you can find `value(forKey:)` there.

Comment: but i found this in my xcode so what about this not take it personally i just looking for answer @OOPer

Comment: i am also newer in swift so just clear this stuff in my mind can you help me out please @OOPer

Comment: Xcode shows many other methods. Have you checked all of them if it may just work for this purpose? If there may be others, you recommend to use any of them? It's just sort of coincident that `value(forKey:)` seemingly worked in this case. Do you use `let i = unsafeBitCast(Int.self, to: nil as UnsafeRawPointer?)` to assign `0` into `i`. What you are doing is very similar to it. Do not rely on luck, use the right method for your purpose.

Comment: The root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies, from which subclasses inherit a basic interface to the runtime system and the ability to behave as Objective-C objects. check this in Relationships in bottom of the document where u found this stuff @OOPer

Comment: Do you think I do not know such things? Such methods have their own purpose. It's just a luck `value(forKey:)` worked similar to some methods intended to retrieve values form `UserDefaults`. I repeat, do not rely on luck.

Comment: `valueForKey` is a key-value coding method of `NSObject`, the root class of `UserDefaults`. All `NSObject` methods are displayed in code completion also for the subclasses. KVC has a special functionality and should be only used if KVC is intended. There is no serious reason at all to use KVC with `UserDefaults`.

Comment: such knowledge in this discussion! I wish I could understand what everyone mean :) just began coding two weeks ago but very interesting read nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way (by Apple!) is to register key/value pairs in `UserDefaults` to provide – as the class name implies – default values. Those default values are considered until the value is changed the first time.

The Swift benefit is that there is always a (non-optional) value which can be unwrapped safely.

As soon as possible (e.g. `applicationWillFinishLaunching`) add these lines. They are supposed to be executed every time the application launches. The key `Nb` is registered with an empty string default value.

```
let defaultValues = ["Nb" : ""]
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: defaultValues)
```

---

In `storeButton` **don't remove the key** and don't use String Interpolation for a `String` but check if the text property is `nil` and save an empty string in this case. The print line is nonsensical because reading from `UserDefaults` right after writing will not get the changes and you **know** what's been written

```
@IBAction func storeButton(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(phoneLabel.text ?? "", forKey: "Nb")
}
```

---

In `retrieveButton` get the string with the dedicated method `string(forKey`, unwrap it (due to registering the key there is always a value) and only check for empty string. And don't read the (same) value 3 times.

```
@IBAction func retrieveButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let phoneNbDisplay = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Nb")!
    if phoneNbDisplay.isEmpty {
        phoneDisplayLabel.text = "enter a number first"
    } else {
        phoneDisplayLabel.text = "Your NB is \(phoneNbDisplay)"
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand well in the first part you tell swift to replace the optional by a default empty value 
 - then in the second part you have to define the object as an optional with empty string value because of the first part swift does not give it an optional automatically?

Comment: Did my code not work because swift was creating an optional and therefore not seeing a nil value and you method replaces this default optional ?

Comment: In my code there is no optional at all. Although `stringForKey` returns an optional value by default here it's guaranteed that there is always a value. Your code is a bit confusing I can't see the particular reason of the error.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I'll try to understand later when I have more experience

Answer (score 1):

As vadian commented, you should not and have no need to use KVC method `value(forKey:)` in this case.

Try this:

```
@IBAction func storeButton(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Nb")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(phoneLabel.text ?? "", forKey: "Nb") //<-You have no need to use String Interpolation.
    print (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Nb") as Any)
}

@IBAction func retrieveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if let phoneNB = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Nb") {
        if !phoneNB.isEmpty {
            phoneDisplayLabel.text = "Your NB is \(phoneNB)"
        } else {
            phoneDisplayLabel.text = "enter a number first"
        }
    } else {
        //### What do you want to do if "Nb" is not set?
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might forget to call synchronize while storing value.You can try this.

```
@IBAction func storeButton(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Nb")
    UserDefaults.standard.set("\(phoneLabel.text!)", forKey: "Nb")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    print (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Nb") as Any)
}

@IBAction func retrieveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if let phoneNB = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Nb"){
         phoneDisplayLabel.text = "Your NB is \(phoneNB)"
    }else {
         phoneDisplayLabel.text = "enter a number first"
    }
}
```